# Solve an unusual error in a sequelize join

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am getting an unusual error when trying to run a join in sequelize.  The error message is

> SequelizeEagerLoadingError: tblSMS is associated to tblSMSSent using an alias. You've included an alias (tblSMS), but it does not match the alias(es) defined in your association (tblSM).

The join I have created is this:

```
userDB.tblSMSSent.belongsTo(userDB.tblSMS, { foreignKey: 'MessageId', targetKey: 'OutgoingMessageId' });
    userDB.tblSMS.hasMany(userDB.tblSMSSent, { targetKey: 'OutgoingMessageId' });

    let messages = await userDB.tblSMSSent.findAll({
        attributes: [
            ['phone', 'phone'],
            ['date', 'date'],
            [sequelize.fn('substring', sequelize.col('result'), 1, 50), 'result'],
            ['debtor', 'debtor'],
            ['sms', 'OrigBody'],
            ['user', 'user'],
            ['MessageId', 'MessageId']
        ],
        offset: startVal,
        include: {
            model: userDB.tblSMS,
            as: 'tblSMS',
            attributes: [['MessageBody', 'MessageText']]
        },
        logging: console.log
    })
```

The definitions for the 2 tables were created using sequelize-auto with no correspondences between the 2 tables.

**tblSMS**

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define('tblSMS', {
    id: {
      autoIncrement: true,
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    Destination: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(20),
      allowNull: true
    },
    MessageBody: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT,
      allowNull: true
    },
    MessageNumber: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: true
    },
    OutgoingMessageId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: true
    },
    PhoneNumber: {
      type: DataTypes.CHAR(20),
      allowNull: true
    },
    ReceivedDate: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      allowNull: true
    },
    Reference: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT,
      allowNull: true
    },
    exported: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      allowNull: true,
      defaultValue: false
    },
    Key: {
      type: DataTypes.CHAR(32),
      allowNull: true
    },
    Province: {
      type: DataTypes.CHAR(2),
      allowNull: true
    },
    OrigBody: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT,
      allowNull: true
    },
    OrigNumber: {
      type: DataTypes.CHAR(20),
      allowNull: true
    },
    OrigCredits: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: true
    },
    OrigQueueDate: {
      type: DataTypes.DATEONLY,
      allowNull: true
    },
    OrigSendDate: {
      type: DataTypes.DATEONLY,
      allowNull: true
    },
    OrigSent: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      allowNull: true
    },
    OrigSuccess: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
      allowNull: true
    },
    AccountKey: {
      type: DataTypes.BLOB,
      allowNull: true
    }
  }, {
    sequelize,
    tableName: 'tblSMS',
    schema: 'dbo',
    timestamps: false,
    indexes: [
      {
        name: "PK_tblSMS",
        unique: true,
        fields: [
          { name: "id" },
        ]
      },
    ]
  });
};
```

**tblSMSSent**

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define('tblSMSSent', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    user: {
      type: DataTypes.CHAR(10),
      allowNull: false
    },
    phone: {
      type: DataTypes.CHAR(15),
      allowNull: false
    },
    sms: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT,
      allowNull: true
    },
    date: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      allowNull: false
    },
    result: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT,
      allowNull: true
    },
    debtor: {
      type: DataTypes.CHAR(20),
      allowNull: false
    },
    exported: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: false
    },
    messageID: {
      type: DataTypes.CHAR(20),
      allowNull: true
    }
  }, {
    sequelize,
    tableName: 'tblSMSSent',
    schema: 'dbo',
    timestamps: false
  });
};
```

This error started appearing when I attempted to add a custom getter method to tblSMSSent by extending the definition (which I was unable to get working - I wanted to add a '^' before the text retrieved from tblSMSSent).

The unusual thing about this error is that nowhere in the code is there any text found with simply "tblSM" as the error message is reporting as an alias used.

I have stopped and restarted Node several times to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is stating that you have an alias in the `include` part of the `findAll` query, but that there is no corresponding alias in the definition of the association between the two tables.  Try having just

```
include: {
    model: userDB.tblSMS,
    attributes: [['MessageBody', 'MessageText']]
},
```

in the `findAll` query.  That will remove the reference to an undefined alias.

Also, the line

```
userDB.tblSMS.hasMany(userDB.tblSMSSent, { targetKey: 'OutgoingMessageId' });
```

should be changed to

```
userDB.tblSMS.hasMany(userDB.tblSMSSent, { sourceKey: 'OutgoingMessageId' });
```

since `OutgoingMessageId` is a property of the source model rather than the target model.  You could even add the `foreignKey` property to the `hasMany` association, so that

```
userDB.tblSMS.hasMany(userDB.tblSMSSent, {
        sourceKey: 'OutgoingMessageId',
        foreignKey: 'MessageId'
    });
```

Comment: It was the as: 'tblSMS' that was causing the problem.  I tried all variations you gave and it worked with everything else.  Thank you.